# Why there are nan values when I do df.describe()?

Tags: python, pandas

When I do `df.describe()`, it shows NaN in 25%, 50% and 75%.
I only have a few in nan numbers, and shouldn't `describe()` only consider numeric numbers for default parameter `'include=None`'?
mean, std, min, max, count are normal.

Thanks very much!

Comment: It's a bug that's fixed for dev. version https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13098

Comment: Thanks, I also noticed the bug in quantile function.